# SelectionColor being applied in some instances and not in others

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the below method that *should* be highlighting certain lines of text in a rich text box while also replacing the existing line with a new line that includes a comment (error/success).

This method works with one file, works with 2 files, but anything more than that will result in some of the middle strings not getting the color correctly. I'm new to C# and not sure if there's some nuance I'm missing.

Hopefully the below is enough to assist, but essentially the result in the UI is that the first file is green, the second is green despite being an error and the logging showing that it should be red, and the last file is correctly displayed as red.

Here is the code:

```
private void updateFileList(string fileName, string newFileName, Color color)
    {

        string matchString = Regex.Escape(fileName);
        Console.WriteLine(matchString);
        Console.WriteLine(color);
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(tbFileList.Text, matchString))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MATCH: " + match);
            tbFileList.Text = tbFileList.Text.Replace(fileName, newFileName);
            tbFileList.SelectionStart = match.Index;
            Console.WriteLine("INDEX: " + match.Index.ToString());
            tbFileList.SelectionLength = newFileName.Length;
            Console.WriteLine("LENGTH: " + newFileName.Length.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("SELECTED TEXT: " + tbFileList.SelectedText);
            tbFileList.SelectionColor = color;
            Console.WriteLine("SELECTION COLOR: " + tbFileList.SelectionColor);

        };
    }
```

And here is the result of the `Console.WriteLine` statements:

```
===================
A:\\FileName1\.txt
Color [Green]
MATCH: A:\FileName1.txt
INDEX: 0
LENGTH: 102
SELECTED TEXT: A:\FileName1.txt | Success!
SELECTION COLOR: Color [Green]
===================
A:\\FileName2\.txt
Color [Red]
MATCH: A:\FileName2.txt
INDEX: 103
LENGTH: 164
SELECTED TEXT: A:\FileName2.txt | ERROR.
SELECTION COLOR: Color [Red]
===================
A:\\Filename3\.txt
Color [Red]
MATCH: A:\Filename3.txt
INDEX: 268
LENGTH: 147
SELECTED TEXT: A:\Filename3.txt | ERROR.
SELECTION COLOR: Color [Red]
```

**NOTE**

I've changed the file names so the index/length may not make sense if you're comparing it to the file name. They seem to line up sequentially though, so I'm fairly certain it's not grabbing the wrong portion of text or something.

Calling the above method like this:

`updateFileList(fileName, newFileName, Color.Red);`

**EDIT**

Changed to this instead and no change:

```
string newText = tbFileList.Text.Replace(fileName, newFileName);
tbFileList.Text = newText;
```

**EDIT 2**

I also tried this:

```
string newText = tbFileList.Text;
tbFileList.Text = newText.Replace(fileName, newFileName);
```

Comment: You are not supposed to change the Text directly. Use  `rtb.SelectedText = newText` instead and for formatted new texts use Copy and Paste !

Comment: I edited my question, but not sure i'm fully following your suggestion correctly.

Comment: I need to replace one line of text in the rtb and then change the color of the newly replaced line, while leaving other lines unchanged.

Comment: `tbFileList.Text = ...` destroys all existing formatting.  A RichTextBox does all it's formatting work through the rtb.SelectionXXX commands.

Comment: so then maybe I can change the text first for all the lines, then after the loop apply formatting?

Comment: @Lars: Of course I am talking about [rtb.Copy/paste etc](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.paste?view=netframework-4.8) , which is the recommended way to move already formatted text.

Comment: @hyphon: `tbFileList.Text = ` this is a mistake as I and Lars ha noted. Select the line and then use my code plusr SelextionColo = yourColor..

Comment: @TaW Those are for a RichText editor type program/control if you design one.  If I put something on the clipboard and a program unbeknownst to me replaces my clipboard information, I won't be a happy user.

Comment: Remove this: `tbFileList.Text = tbFileList.Text.Replace(fileName, newFileName);`. Change this: `tbFileList.SelectionLength = newFileName.Length;` in this: `tbFileList.SelectionLength = match.Length;` and you're ok.